# Change classes of multiple hyperlinks OnClick in a group. Multiple groups on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, menu, onclick

I've been searching for the past couple of days, however, I haven't been able to find a solution which resolves all the constraints I'm currently facing.  Any help would be much appreciated.

jQuery is already being used on the page.

### Current Scenario

I have an existing page with multiple panels.  Each panel has a small navigation menu (a horizontal UL list) which is used to Show/Hide layers within that panel.  The Show/Hide function is working as intended.

### What is missing

Highlight currently active menu item when clicked and restore the previously active item to inactive by changing class.

### Constraints

1. The classes - active/inactive are applied to `<a>` tag
2. The design is such that both the active/inactive classes are unique i.e. we can not assign a common class (e.g. .selected) to a group of or all hyperlinks
3. There are multiple such unique groups on the page and I need to be able to target them individually.

### jsFiddle

Please refer to the [jsFiddle illustration here](http://jsfiddle.net/eEyqf/12/).

### HTML Code

The basic block of HTML that I'm working with is as follows:

```
<div id="panel">
  <div id="navwrapper">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="javascript:showhide('div_1');" class="grp1_1_selected">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:showhide('div_2');" class="grp1_2">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:showhide('div_3');" class="grp1_3">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="div_1" name="group1">Some content here for Div 1</div>
  <div id="div_2" name="group1">Some content here for Div 2</div>
  <div id="div_3" name="group1">Some content here for Div 3</div>
</div>
```

There are multiple such panels (each unique) on the page, thus the other similar solutions fail to work.

Comment: have you uses jQueryUI before? it has tab functionality in it that is very easy to use: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: @gordatron jQueryUI tabs would work but need a lot of code changes. At the moment I need to work with the existing code with minimal changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul#nav > li > a').on('click', function() {

    $('ul#nav a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('class', function() {
           return this.className.replace('_selected','');
        })
    });
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr('class') + '_selected');

});
```

Check this out:

***[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/eEyqf/13/)***

Another ***[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/WsQsa/1/)***

In DEMO2, I use `ul.nav` a common class to all `ul`, so that you can change and various ids for different `ul`s.

I think you need something like this.

Comment: Is there any way to include multiple IDs in the same script? e.g. #nav1, #nav2, #nav3 etc. That way I wouldn't have to specify the same script individually for all of them.

(I'm sorry if that's an obvious answer but I'm not very JavaScript savvy)

Comment: @CuriousCat it is possible to include multiple UNIQUE ids

Comment: so, where all would I have to add #nav1, #nav2 etc. in the above code?  could you please illustrate.

Comment: @CuriousCat do you wanna include multiple ids for multiple group?

Comment: Yes. I would like to include IDs of all other ULs if possible.  Since we are targeting children of #nav (li > a) in the example above, it'd be great if we were able to include (li > a) for, let's say all, #nav, #nav1, #nav2 etc.  As the only thing which will change is the ID in the script, might as well combine into a single script.

Comment: @CuriousCat see my DEMO2, here I write my code class, not id.So you can add different id to each ul.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple such panels then you should use classes

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="navwrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a class="selected">One</a></li>
      <li><a>Two</a></li>
      <li><a>Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel_content">Some content here for Div 1</div>
  <div class="panel_content">Some content here for Div 2</div>
  <div class="panel_content">Some content here for Div 3</div>
</div>
```

and you can use this code to handle them.

```
  $('.panel').each(function() {
     var panel = $(this);
     var a = $(this).find('.nav a').click(function() {
        panel.find('.panel_content').eq(a.index(this)).show().
           siblings('.panel_content').hide();
        $(this).addClass('selected').parent().siblings().
           children().removeClass('selected');
     });
  });
```

it will work for all panels

Comment: Each panel design is unique, as is their content thus the use of IDs. Besides, changing to IDs to classes in existing code is not going to be possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery, you shouldn't add the js function to href tag, check my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eEyqf/14/) for a better solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav li a').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('href').substring(1).split('-');
    $('a.group'+target[0]).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('div.group'+target[0]).hide();
    $('div#div_'+target[1]+'.group'+target[0]).show();
}); 
});​
```

Note that

1. the links only contain an anchor (e.g. #1-2) which can even be used to bookmark a specific content. (More js required.)
2. the CSS still is able to display an image for each tab.

Comment: This works, however, it'd require substantial changes to the existing CSS in my case.

Comment: Frankly, your CSS can be improved. I think it's not wise to have classes like `group_1_selected`. This is rather an id. Work with multiple classes like `group_1 selected` to be able to easier handle different cases and to minimize your CSS.